# Randomly picking a column index depending on the weight of its value (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, random

I'm having some trouble explicitly stating what I'm trying to do, so I'll be elaborate. I have a matrix A (n by n), with only zeroes and ones. Now, what I'm trying to do is randomly pick one of the columns (so from 1 to n), but the more ones there are in a column, the more likely it should be that I pick that column. So, to begin with I defined their weights as

```
 weight = sum(A,1);
 weight = weight/sum(weight);
```

which gives me a weight from 0 to 1. Not sure if that's easier than it being 0 to N, but ok. Here's where I get stuck though.. How do I now randomly pick one of these N values, dependent on the actual value? I really don't know, to be honest.

Comment: I'm thinking I need to calculate the cdf, and then generate a bunch of random numbers, and see what interval they fall into. Not completely sure how to do that though.

Comment: That's a good approach, but `randsample` does that for you (see my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`randsample`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) (Statistics Toolbox), which allows you to specify weights:

```
col = randsample(1:size(A,2), 1, true, weight);
```

and then your column is `A(:,col)`.

If you don't have the Statistics Toolbox:

```
col = sum(rand<cumsum(weight));
```

Comment: Sometimes I'm amazed by how many powerful inbuilt functions there are, and my lack of finding-them abilities. Thank you very much, this is basically all I needed.

Comment: @user129412 Welcome! This one isn't really built-in, though; it's part of a Toolbox. Those are harder to know about!